# Shiny renderPlot does not work

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

**Problem:**

The graph plot does not Render. There are no errors.

**Description:**

Even though I do not use a reactive value below, it should work because it is within an observed event. Rendering a table works perfectly fine.

**Additional Info**

The AllElements Data is definitely populated! I printed them out to check. They are vectors of type double.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinythemes)
library(datasets)

shinyApp(
  ui = navbarPage(
    "Real Time Instruments",
    #############################    Page 1     #############################
    tabPanel("Training",

             mainPanel(

               actionButton("analyse", "Train Model", width = "100%")

             )
             #############################    Page 2     #############################
    ),
    tabPanel("Results",

               tableOutput ( "error"),
               plotOutput("predict_plot", inline = TRUE)

    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    ### Analyse the data
    analyse <- observeEvent(input$analyse , {

      # Run the Analysis
      AllElements <- data.frame( x = 1:10 )

      # populate the results
      populateResults (AllElements)
    })

    #### Results Page ####
    populateResults <- function (allElements) {

      # First the error table
      output$error <- renderTable(allElements$error_sd, digits = 5) ## <--- THIS WORKS!!!

      # Second Plots
      # par(mar = rep(2, 4)) # Might be needed

      x <- allElements$x
      xlab <- allElements$x
      y <- allElements$x
      ylab <- allElements$x

      # Plot Predict Var
      output$predict_plot <- renderPlot({plot (x, y)}) # <--- THIS DOESN'T WORK!!!

    }
  })
  }
)
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. The mistake could also be in the UI. So please share the code for an app. You also didn't describe what exactly doesn't work. Is there no plot? Is an error message displayed?

Comment: @FelixGrossmann Updated.

Comment: I updated your code. It did not work for me because of missing brackets and some commas. After all it still does not work because there is no `AnalyseData` available.

Comment: @FelixGrossmann I echanged it with dummy data. it should work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change several things in your code.

- I transformed the data into an `eventReactive`
- I didn't use your function `populateResults` and replaced it by independent render functions
- I added a column `error_sd` to the example dataset so that it can be found later in the render functions
- I don't know if I missed something here, just have a look at my code.

This example works for me:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinythemes)
library(datasets)

shinyApp(
  ui = navbarPage(
    "Real Time Instruments",
    tabPanel("Training",

         mainPanel(

           actionButton("analyse", "Train Model", width = "100%")

         )
),
tabPanel("Results",

         tableOutput ( "error"),
         plotOutput("predict_plot")

) 
),
 server = function(input, output, session) {

analyse <- eventReactive(input$analyse , {
  output <- data.frame( x = 1:10 , error_sd = 1:10)
  return(output)
})

output$error <- renderTable({
  analyse()$error_sd} , digits = 5
)

output$predict_plot <- renderPlot({
  # x <- allElements$x
  # xlab <- allElements$x
  # y <- allElements$x
  # ylab <- allElements$x

  plot(analyse()$x, analyse()$x)
})
})
```

Comment: The issue with the data above is that I cannot run analyse()$error_sd everytime I want a result, concidering each call of the function can take up to an hour.

Would it work if I used the results of the analyse function:

AllElements <- reactiveValues()

output$error <- renderTable () {
 output$error_sd <- AllElements$error_sd
}

Comment: I don't know if I understand you correctly. I answer my both interpretations of your comment. If you don't want that `analyse()` is calculated everytime with some other data, you could use another button instead of `input$analyse` just for this task. So you would split training the model from the data generation.
Second interpretation: if you just want that the addicted parts of the data like the table or the plot don't throw errors while the data is loading, you can use `need()` and `validate()`.

Comment: If you are speaking german, you can read my blogpost about the topic: http://felixgrossmann.com/2017/04/03/eingabenvalidierung-in-r-shiny/ . Alternatively you can read the official post: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html If I didn't understand you correctly, please try to describe it in another way. I don't get your code, because `analyse()` doesn't pop up there.